# "Cannot read properties of undefined" when rendering a list of objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to render a list of objects by their name in Vue 3, but I keep getting a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')" error.

[image]

I'm still new to Vue, and I have no idea why it cannot read the object name. If someone could help direct me to the right direction, then that would be great.

Thanks

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
    <header>
        <div id="header-content">
            <div id="header-left">
                <img v-bind:src="require('@/assets/clover.png')">
            </div>
            <div id="header-center">
                <div class="header-link">
                    <router-link style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" to="/">Home</router-link>
                </div>
                <div class="header-link dropdown">
                    <!-- <router-link style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" to="/products">Shop</router-link> -->


                    <p>Shop</p>
                    <ul class="dropdown-content">
                        <li :v-for="category in categories" class="dropdown-link">
                            {{ category.name }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <div class="header-link">
                    <router-link style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" to="/about">About Us</router-link>
                </div>
                <div class="header-link">
                    <router-link style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" to="/faq">FAQ</router-link>
                </div>
                <div class="header-link">
                    <router-link style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" to="/contact">Contact Us</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="header-right">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" width="37" height="37"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16 11V7a4 4 0 00-8 0v4M5 9h14l1 12H4L5 9z"></path></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
    name: "Header",
    setup() {
        let categories = ref([{name: "Test"}, {name: "Test 2"}])

        return {
            categories
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's `<li v-for`, not `<li :v-for`

Comment: @EstusFlask I understand that. But Vue3 gives me an "Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives" error if I don't bind the for loop.

Comment: It means what it says, you need to preferably  have :key in addition to v-for. This is a warning and not error, it's expected to work as is. In your case name is unique and it would be `<li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.name"`

Comment: `:v-for` isn't even a v-for, it's a new binding with the name "v-for" which Vue then treats like a prop, not as an actual v-for, and as a side effect is causing your other errors.  you need to follow correct syntax.  also, the warning about `key` is from eslint.  you can ignore it (not advisable), turn the eslint rule [off](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules) (also not advisable), or heed the advice of the warning and add the [key](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes#key) attribute!

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize the "v-if" directive to ensure that the variable is defined before rendering the list as below

```
<ul class="dropdown-content" v-if="categories">
  <li v-for="category in categories" class="dropdown-link">
    {{ category.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still giving me the same issue. Could it be because I'm binding the v-for tag? Because all the examples I've seen online don't bind the for loop tag, but vue gives me an error if I don't bind it.